# libpq.dylib x86 client library

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firedac, c++builder-tokyo

I have a FMX application that should run in Windows and MAC. The application uses FireDac and needs to connect with Postgresql and Firebird. The windows side works perfectly. On the MAC side I was able to find the x86 dylib files and make it work, but I have not been able to find the libpq.dylib x86 client library.
Can anyone point me to where I can download the x86 version of libpq.dylib?
Thank you
Sam

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please read the entire page, not just the first paragraph or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the x86 dylib from pgadmin v3 (for Mac, of course). That is a 32 bit application.